# Windows 10 upgrade deleted my Users junction, won't let me rename old Users dir

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Years ago when I set up my PC on Windows 7, I followed [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7) to create a junction from my SSD (C:\Users) to my HDD (E:\Users) so that my Users directory would be on the larger drive.

However, I just noticed recently that, sometime between then and now (possibly during the Windows 10 upgrade?) this junction has vanished; C:\Users is actually on the SSD with most of my files, and the old E:\Users directory is mostly cleared out (a few scattered files left around, but mostly empty directories).

Since there didn't seem to be anything left to clean up, I was getting ready to follow [these instructions](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-users-folder-move-location-windows-10-a.html#MethodTwo) to move the Users directory anew, but wanted to rename the original E:\Users first to get it out of the way. That's when I noticed an oddity; I can't rename E:\Users (to, say, E:\OldUsers) to get the empty husk out of the way prior to setting up the new solution. The GUI lets me enter a new name for the folder, but doesn't display it after submission. Whatever name I choose does show up correctly when I run dir in the dos prompt, but windows explorer insists that the directory is called "Users" no matter what I do.

With all this in mind: has my original junction setup possibly left some registry cruft behind that would be causing the weird "stuck" directory name? Is there another explanation? Is it safe for me to try the Sysprep solution for moving my Users directory, or is the phantom E:\Users going to cause me problems? Above all else, how do I fix this?

I should note that I'm mostly an Ubuntu guy and know just barely enough to get myself in trouble working under the hood on Windows, so your patience is appreciated.

Comment: I can't confirm this, which it is not an answer but comment: I think it is locked by the c:\windows.old folder so you can downgrade back. It is likely still a junction, but pointing to c:\windows.old instead.

Comment: Unless that directory is hidden somehow I don't see a windows.old dir on either C: nor E: using dir /a /l

Comment: If you boot an Ubuntu Live CD, you should be able to do all your renaming and copying from there, though I wouldn't try to mess with the junction entry. Back up first, of course.